# Selenium automated mouse click not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need help with automating a button click using selenium. Here is the HTML code of where the button lives:

```
<div class="q02Nz _0TPg" data-testid="new-post-button" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">
<svg aria-label="New Post" class="_8-yf5 " fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
```

I've tried the below lines of python code, but they're not working:

1)

```
adder = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='q02Nz._0TPg']")
adder.click()
```

2. 

```
adder = browser.find_element_by_class_name('q02Nz._0TPg')
adder.click()
```

Etc.

Anyway, I've tried a few others, but I don't remember what they were. Let me know what I can do to make this code work! Thanks.

Comment: If this question is no longer valid, please delete this question so others don't try to answer it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are searching by the name of the class, you wouldn't substitute a period for the separating space. Thus, it should be:

```py
adder = browser.find_element_by_class_name("q02Nz _0TPg")
adder.click()
```

This is the same for the XPath:

```py
adder = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='q02Nz _0TPg']")
adder.click()
```

Note that the substitution of periods for spaces is only needed when using CSS selectors, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was running into with this code, was due to the line of code before it. So there was no issue with what I was trying to do with this button.